# Retornar uma matriz de uma função em C

Tags: funções, matriz, return

Olá, estou fazendo um programa em C que exige ser modularizado, que o usuário cadastra os cursos desejados, imprime na tela os cursos,mas desejo usar a matriz de cursos, em outra função, como retornar essa matriz para outra matriz na main?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void nomecursos(int qtd){
    char matrizcursos[qtd][100];
    int i,confirm;
    do {
    for(i=0;i<qtd; i++){
        printf("Digite o %d curso\n",i);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(matrizcursos[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<qtd;i++){
        printf("Cursos Cadastrados; %s\n", matrizcursos[i]);
    }
    printf("Confirmar cursos cadastrados ? Digite 1 para comfirmar ou 0 para cadastrar novamente\n");
    scanf("%d", &confirm);
    }while(confirm == 0);
    return;
}
int main(){
    int cursos;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de cursos\n");
    scanf("%d", &cursos);
    nomecursos(cursos);
    printf("Digite o nome do curso que deseja cadastrar uma proposta\n");

}
```

Comment: Não me parece modularizado.

Comment: O que foi pedido ou meu codigo ?